# Can I disable apache mod_setenvif if I'm using as reverse proxy NGinx?

Tags: apache, http, nginx

I've installed Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of my existing apache server. All my requests are routed from Nginx server to Apache.

Can I disable mod_setenvif in my apache server?

Web<->Nginx<->Apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable `mod_setenvif` if you are not using any of the functionality provided by that module: the `BrowserMatch`, `BrowserMatchNoCase`, `SetEnvIf`, and `SetEnvIfNoCase` directives. Nginx has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Tks.. Saving a few KBs of RAM in a very busy server